# How to translate "transparent communication" to Mandarin?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I was writing an email for work and was trying to translate the term "transparent communication" to Chinese, but realized I didn't know the term at all.  I'm pretty sure 透明的 isn't correct, but closest term I can find or think of was 明晰的.  I'd like to know if there's another phrase that fits better?

EDIT: Usage example in the form of a sentence...

> The administration is committed to fostering a new paradigm of **transparent** and accountable communications, and will be developing the necessary internal training and SOP's as guidance to achieve this culture.

Comment: Write the sentence in which you use the term, then it can be translated.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays 透明 can also mean transparent in the sense of openness as a calque from English.

Though 透明沟通 or 透明的沟通 indeed sounds a bit weird to me. But 开放透明的沟通 (open and transparent communication) is okay. 透明的沟通机制 (transparent communication mechanism) and 透明的沟通平台 (transparent communication platform) are fine too.

Edit: I would translate "a new paradigm of transparent and accountable communications" as 透明且负责任的沟通新范式.

Answer (score 0):

try 坦诚地沟通.i think it's what you mean transparency

Comment: #J Wang, Yes, 透明, though meaning "transparent" does not really have the same connotation as it does in English. In Chinese it is more of transparent in the physical rather than metaphysical sense.  坦诚, (more like "frankness"), is more suited in the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a common translation for SOP so I put : 标准作业程序 maybe there is a better phrase. Baidu has 标准操作程序. Either will do.

Looks like 透明 is good here, with a meaning of 'non-secretive'.

The administration is committed to fostering a new paradigm of transparent and accountable communications
行政当局致力于建立透明和负责人的沟通新模式

and will be developing the necessary internal training and Standard Operating Procedures as guidance to achieve this culture.
并将制定必要的内部培训和标准作业程序作为实现这种文化的指导。